# 3 levels of wordpress category dependency

Tags: wordpress

My task is to display 3 levels of categories **Country** - **Region** - **City** in select.

That is, if i choose the country Spain, the subcategories of Spain should be displayed in the regions and cities. And when I select the Mallorca region, only the cities in the Mallorca region, Spain should be listed.

[How it should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtvcV.png)

If country is not selected, all countries, regions and cities should be displayed in select.

How can i do it? I'll be very thankful for any ideas and hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it works for me.

```
<?php
$level = get_the_level( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'city' );
$parent_terms = get_terms(array (
    'taxonomy' => 'city',
    'parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields' => 'ids'
)); ?>

<div class="blog-nav">
    <div class="blog-nav__title"><?php _e('Select country', 'bike'); ?></div>
    <select class="modal-form__input" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('rental-stations'); ?>"><?php _e('All', 'bike'); ?></option>   
        <?php foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
            $check_term = get_terms(array (
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'child_of' => $pterm,
                'orderby' => 'slug',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'fields' => 'ids'
            ));
            if ( get_queried_object()->term_id == $pterm || in_array(get_queried_object()->term_id, $check_term) ) {
                $selected = 'selected';
            } else {
                $selected = '';
            }
            $option = '<option '.$selected.' value="'.get_category_link($pterm).'">';
            $option .= get_term( $pterm )->name;
            $option .= '</option>';
            echo $option;
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="blog-nav">
    <div class="blog-nav__title"><?php _e('Select region', 'bike') ?></div>
    <select class="modal-form__input" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="<?php echo get_category_link(get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent); ?>"><?php _e('All', 'bike'); ?></option>   
        <?php 
        if ($level == 0) {
            $child_of = get_queried_object()->term_id;
            $parent = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        } elseif ($level == 1) {
            $child_of = get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent;
            $parent = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        } elseif ($level == 2) {
            $child_of = get_term(get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent)->parent;
            $parent = get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent;
        }
        $terms = get_terms(array (
            'taxonomy' => 'city',
            'orderby' => 'slug', 
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'child_of' => $child_of
        ));
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if ( get_term($term)->parent && category_has_children($term, 'city') ) { 
                if ( get_queried_object()->term_id == $term || get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent == $term ) {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                } else {
                    $selected = '';
                }
                $option = '<option '.$selected.' value="'.get_category_link($term).'">';
                $option .= get_term( $term )->name;
                $option .= '</option>';
                echo $option;
            }
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="blog-nav">
    <div class="blog-nav__title"><?php _e('Select city', 'bike') ?></div>  
    <select class="modal-form__input" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="<?php echo get_category_link(get_term(get_queried_object()->term_id)->parent) ?>"><?php _e('All', 'bike'); ?></option>   
        <?php $cterms = get_terms(array (
            'taxonomy' => 'city',
            'orderby' => 'slug', 
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'child_of' => $parent
        ));
        foreach ($cterms as $cterm) {
            if (get_term($cterm)->parent && !category_has_children($cterm, 'city')) { 
                if ( get_queried_object()->term_id == $cterm ) {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                } else {
                    $selected = '';
                }
                $option = '<option '.$selected.' value="'.get_category_link($cterm).'">';
                $option .= get_term( $cterm )->name;
                $option .= '</option>';
                echo $option;
            }
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```